# How to melt four column in the same table in one column with pandas.melt

Tags: pandas, dataframe, analytics

I am learning data analytics and have a project which need 4 column to melt in one column and using - between them
Ex puppo none doggo none
We want them in one column
As puppo-doggo

Comment: Please share some example data. And have a look at the [docs for pandas melt function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your source DataFrame contains:

```
   id  A  B   C   D
0  X1  1  5   9  12
1  X2  2  6  10  14
2  X3  3  7  11  15
3  X4  4  8  12  16
```

To melt columns *A* thru *D* you can run:

```
result = df.melt(id_vars=['id'], value_vars=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    var_name='Column', value_name='Value')
```

The result is:

```
    id Column  Value
0   X1      A      1
1   X2      A      2
2   X3      A      3
3   X4      A      4
4   X1      B      5
5   X2      B      6
6   X3      B      7
7   X4      B      8
8   X1      C      9
9   X2      C     10
10  X3      C     11
11  X4      C     12
12  X1      D     12
13  X2      D     14
14  X3      D     15
15  X4      D     16
```

Read the documentation cocerning *melt* and experiment with
other setting of available parameters and their default values.

Comment: i want new column show 1-5-9-12 and dash - between them and notice also there are some missing data in column i mean if i have data like 1  5   none  12  i want new column 1-5-12

Comment: *Melt* is something totally different than creation of new columns. Probably this is material for another question.